# Django sorl.thumbnail issues

Tags: django

Can't seem to get sorl.thumnail to create thumbnails. It just creates empty files.

Say, tried uploading  3.gif, the original file gets uploaded fine, thumbnail does not created, it creates a file with 0 bytes:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 14128 2010-02-13 06:57 3.gif
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data     0 2010-02-13 06:57 3_gif_200x200_autocrop_q85.jpg
```

The template looks like this

```
{% thumbnail photo.photo 200x200 autocrop as thumb %}
<img src="{{ thumb }}" width="{{ thumb.width }}" height="{{ thumb.height }}" alt="{{ photo.title }}" />
```

Comment: Does your PIL installation have all the relevant libraries? What does your /var/log/syslog (or equivalent) say?

Answer (score 0):

Had to reinstall PIL

Comment: Thanks for the tip. How did you decided to reinstall PIL...you found some specific error messages?

Comment: How did you reinstall ? Form source?